# Error en funcion dentro de objeto

Tags: javascript, nodejs, funciones

```js
module.exports = {
  post: (title, body, autor) => {
    this.title = title
    this.body = body
    this.autor = autor
  },
  search: function(search, arr , call){
    var result = arr.find(a => a.title == search)
    call(null, result)
  }
}
```

tengo este codigo cuando lo ejecuto me dice
 "cannot read property find of undefined", antes ya lo he probado a fuera de module.exports. Lo he buscado en google y aqui y no encuentro el error.
muchas gracias,
gracias

Comment: te falta importa algun modulo

Comment: inicializa todas las variables y veras que se solucionara

Comment: me sigue sin funcionar

Comment: no deberia ser asi? `search= function(search, obj , call){
    var result = obj.find(a => a.title == search)
    call(null, result)
  }`

Comment: la sintaxis esta bien

Comment: Me es extraño lo que intentas hacer. Defines un metodo `search`, para un objeto que no es una coleccion. Luego, este metodo `search ` recibe una clave `search`, **un objeto `obj` (solo los `array` tienen `find` y este aca esta seguramente el error)** y un callbak. Puedes agregar el codigo donde invocas este metodo `search` para que veamos cual es el uso que intentas darle?

Comment: queria utilizar objetos pero no podia y cambie a una array, gracias pero hay no esta el error

Comment: > "cannot read property `find` of undefined", quiere decir que obj es null o undefined. Si puedes agregar el codigo desde donde lo llamas podremos ver que esta faltando

Comment: Amigo debe agregar en la pregunta el codigo donde usa la funcion porque de otra forma no podemos replicar el problema que se le esta presentando. En principio su codigo no tiene ningun error de sintaxis y el error que nos comenta es consistente con la respuesta que le han dado.

Answer (score 0):

Claramente el problema es que `arr` es `undefined`, para corregir el error debes agregar una verificación como `typeof arr == 'undefined'` y contemplar el caso o bien remitirte al llamador y hacer la verficación allí para asegurar que el método no falle.

```js
module.exports = {
  post: (title, body, autor) => {
    this.title = title
    this.body = body
    this.autor = autor
  },
  search: function(search, arr , call){
    // ok va a indicar si arr está definido y si arr.find es una función.
    var ok = typeof arr != 'undefined' &&
             typeof arr.find == 'function';
    var result = ok ? arr.find(a => a.title == search) : false;
    call(null, result)
  }
}
```

En la práctica, podrías agregar una condición y avisar al programador que algo no anda bien.